# Partial reset of state with createSlice

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm having an action, which is supposed to do a partial reset on some state properties.

Before moving over to the redux-toolkit, I have achieved this with the following code:

*initialState*

```
const initialState = {
    username: null,
    dateOfBirth: null,
    homeTown: null,
    address: null,
    postCode: null,
    floor: null,
}
```

*reducer*

```
switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case USER_SET_HOME_TOWN:
        return {
            ...initialState,
            homeTown: action.payload
            username: state.userName,
            dateOfBirth: state.dateOfBirth,
        };
    ...
    default:
      return state;
}
```

`USER_SET_HOME_TOWN` is dispatched every time `homeTown` is changing and maintains the username and the dateOfBirth, whilst resting everything else back to the `initialState`.

Now with the redux toolkit and `createSlice` I'm trying to achieve a similar behaviour by writing something like:

*createSlice - not working*

```
const user = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    ...
    reducers: {
        ...
        userSetHomeTown: {
            reducer: (state, action) => {
                state = { ...initialState };
                state.homeTown = action.payload;
                state.username = state.payload;
                state.dateOfBirth = state.dateOfBirth;
            },
        },
        ...
    },
});
```

This isn't working, which, I guess, makes sense since `state = { ...initialState};` resets the `state` and `state.username/dateOfBirth: state.username/dateOfBirth;` are kind of useless then and counter productive... or simply just wrong.

After changing this to:

*createSlice - working*

```
const user = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    ...
    reducers: {
        ...
        userSetHomeTown: {
            reducer: (state, action) => ({
                ...initialState,
                homeTown: action.payload,
                username: state.payload,
                dateOfBirth: state.dateOfBirth,
            }),
        },
        ...
    },
});
```

It did work, but I'm still wondering if this is the recommended and right way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

Remember that Immer works by either *mutating* the existing state object (`state.someField = someValue`), or *returning* an entirely new value you constructed yourself immutably.

Just doing `state = initialState` is neither of those.  All it does is point the local variable `state` to a different reference.

The other option here would be `Object.assign(state, initialState)`, which would overwrite the fields in `state` and thus mutate it.